# why nutch dosen't crawl all links in no English language sites?

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

i crawl a site with nutch 1.4, i understand that nutch dosen't crawl all links in this site. i have no filter and no limit rule to crawling. for example nutch never crawl this link:

http://www.irna.ir/News/30786427/سوء-استفاده-از-نام-كمیته-امداد-برای-جمع-آوری-رای-در-مناطق-محروم/سياسي/

if i give this link to nutch to crawl, nutch never crawl this link. this site is farsi and not English.
how i can crawl this link?

Answer (score 0):

Nutch runs URL normalization and other url processing stuff on each url before adding it the crawldb. Your url might have got filtered there itself. You can remove those plugins from the list of plugins used (`plugin.includes` property in `conf/nutch-site.xml`) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

One reason it might fail to fetch the non-English URL is because different URL-encoding used by the web-server at www.irna.ir and the used nutch client.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! . Please explain your answers in detail .